# Javascript: How did I get here? (Viewing data sent by server, non-AJAX.)

Tags: javascript, http

I've got a React-based app that works like this: The user makes a request for "foo", the server returns basic page info (applicable to all pages on the site), and when the client receives this (DOMContentLoaded), it does an AJAX call for the internal details "foo" and renders that.

But is it possible, if I send the data on the first request, to skip the AJAX call? (I tried this previously but was very new to React, which is how I came up with the current scheme. It's come up again because now I'm handling previously saved items.) So, I'm in my DOMContentLoaded listener, and I can see (in the Browser|Network|Response area of Chrome) all the data that has been sent by the server. It's everything I need, and it's right there, but I can't find a way to access it in Javascript.

The searches I've done have almost all turned up AJAX requests. (I am using JQuery, if that helps.) Obviously I can handle loading saved data using the same gag I'm currently using, and maybe that's a an all-around better approach.

So, once again, the question is: Is it possible to look at the response from a non-AJAX place? If it is possible, is it advisable?

Update: Let me walk through an example scenario.

1. The user goes to "/foo".
2. The server response is {:some "json"}.
3. In the Javascript onReady, I can do this:

   console.log(window.location);

and I'll see "/foo". But can I see {:some "json"}? And how? Contrast with the AJAX call version:

1. The user goes to "/foo".
2. The server response is nothing (i.e., a 200 but no body).
3. The Javascript onReady has:

`$.ajax({
        url: "/foo/data"
        type: "GET",
        success: function (req) {...} //req has {:some data} in it!`

So, when I make an AJAX call, I get the request. Is there any way to get that {:some data} on a non-AJAX call? This doesn't work, but I could see something like:

```
x = window.response();
```

or

```
x = Response.last();
```

Neither of those things exist, of course. I hope that clarifies what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you paste some code that describes your situation a bit more? I've re-read this question a few times and for the life of me i can't figure out what you're asking. Now I really want to know!

Answer (score 0):

You could drop a script tag on your server-rendered page that includes a global var accessible by your script bundle. e.g.,

```
<script>
    var myGlobalVar = { ... server data ... }    <!-- // note: this is rendered raw by your server
</script>
<script src="myScriptBundle.min.js"></script>
```

Or, alternatively you could look into server-side rendering, which is possible with React. Check out the implementation in Redux: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. And have in cases of small amounts of data. But I just have a hard time believing there's no "Hey, what was the response from the server to the request that caused this page to be created?" It may be the case that there just isn't for security reasons or whatever, but I figured someone here would know.